# Configure Web Application Configuration Analyzer 2.0 for my ASP.NET App?

Tags: iis-7

Ok, horrible headline, but the question is, has anyone used the new WACA? I run the scan and for most IIS related Rules I only get "Indeterminate".

For example:
In  element enabled attribute is set to false -> Indeterminate

And that should be something that the tool can determine? No?

Cheers

Remy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS Common Files are required to scan for most of the web server checks. IIS Common Files are native in 2003/XP, but not 2008/Vista/Win7 so you need to install the IIS 6 Mgmt Console, Metabase, and Configuration Utility. Unfortunately this needs to be installed on both the scanning host and the remote server. Why they don't leverage the built-in IIS7 features instead of making you expand your attack surface I don't know.

See this page for instructions for installing IIS Common Files: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998413%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx.